# How to click on element with Chrome DevTools Protocol?

Tags: r, shiny, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm using chromote R package and I'm testing it with shiny application. I'm trying to click on the icon that should duplicate few select elements. But all I have is tooltip when I take a screenshot and if I open the browser it freezes the R process.

Here is my code:

```
#' Run shiny in background - based on shinytest source code
#' @export
shiny.bg <- function(path, loadTimeout = 10000, shinyOptions = list()) {
  tempfile_format <- tempfile("%s-", fileext = ".log")
  p <- callr::r_bg(function(path, shinyOptions) {
    do.call(shiny::runApp, c(path, shinyOptions))
  },
  args = list(
      path = normalizePath(path),
      shinyOptions = shinyOptions
    ),
    stdout = sprintf(tempfile_format, "shiny-stdout"),
    stderr = sprintf(tempfile_format, "shiny-stderr"),
    supervise = TRUE
  )
  if (! p$is_alive()) {
    abort(paste0(
      "Failed to start shiny. Error: ",
      strwrap(readLines(p$get_error_file()))
    ))
  }
  ## Try to read out the port. Try 5 times/sec, until timeout.
  max_i <- loadTimeout / 1000 * 5
  for (i in seq_len(max_i)) {
    err_lines <- readLines(p$get_error_file())

    if (!p$is_alive()) {
      abort(paste0(
        "Error starting application:\n", paste(err_lines, collapse = "\n")
      ))
    }
    if (any(grepl("Listening on http", err_lines))) break

    Sys.sleep(0.2)
  }
  if (i == max_i) {
    abort(paste0(
      "Cannot find shiny port number. Error:\n", paste(err_lines, collapse = "\n")
    ))
  }

  line <- err_lines[grepl("Listening on http", err_lines)]
  m <- rematch::re_match(text = line, "https?://(?<host>[^:]+):(?<port>[0-9]+)")
  
  url <- sub(".*(https?://.*)", "\\1", line)
  
  list(
    process = p,
    url = url
  )
}

#' Run shiny application and Chromeote instance
chromote.shiny <- function() {
  chr <- chromote::ChromoteSession$new()
  app <- shiny.bg('.')
  
  chr$Page$navigate(app$url)
  chr$Page$loadEventFired()
  chr$screenshot()
  
  list(
    chr = chr,
    app = app
  )
}

#' kill browser and R shiny process
cleanUp <- function(obj) {
  obj$chr$Browser$close()
  obj$app$process$kill()
}

#' click on the element
chromote.click <- function(chromote, selector) {
  doc = chromote$DOM$getDocument()
  node = chromote$DOM$querySelector(doc$root$nodeId, selector)
  box <- chromote$DOM$getBoxModel(node$nodeId)
  left <- box$model$content[[1]]
  top <- box$model$content[[2]]
  x <- left + (box$model$width / 2)
  y <- top + (box$model$height / 2)
  chromote$Input$dispatchMouseEvent(type = "mousePressed", x = x, y = y, button="left")
  chromote$Input$dispatchMouseEvent(type = "mouseReleased", x = x, y = y, button="left")
}

tmp <- chromote.shiny()
chromote.click(tmp$chr, ".clone-pair")
tmp$chr$screenshot()
```

I have no idea how I can debug this and there are not much information how to make a click, I've found dispatchMouseEvent in issue in GitHub repo for chromote.

Links to repo https://github.com/rstudio/chromote

The reason why I want to use chromote is I want to create unit/integration test for my application and shinytest is way outdated it use phantomJS that was abandoned years ago (so you need to use very old JavaScript because otherwise pantomJS will throw error and test will fail) and [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium) is also not maintained anymore.

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but there was an issue where a click wouldn't register: https://github.com/mr-yt12/IsTrusted-event-Debugger-API/issues/1
Setting `clickCount` to 1 fixed it

Comment: chrome.debugger.sendCommand({ debuggeeId }, "Input.dispatchMouseEvent", { type: "mousePressed", x, y, button: "left", clickCount: 1 });

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue..

I found this library that uses chromote but has a number of functions (GetElement, Click) from RSelenium.

install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rundel/hayalbaz")